# what is the difference between "distributed data processing" and "distributed computing"?

Tags: terminology, distributed-computing

While going through learning hadoop and spark, I came across "distributed data processing" and "distributed computing".

Could you let me know if they both are same or referring to different concepts?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: See [Distributed Computing on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing).  "Distributed Information Processing" redirects there.  For your purposes, you can probably consider them the same thing.  However, if you like, Distributed Data Processing is the act of using Distributed Computing to process data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### In short

Although in theory there could be a subtle difference, in practice both terms refer to the same concept.

#### In long

According to wikipedia:

> [Computing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing) is any activity that uses computers to manage, process,
>   and communicate information.

and:

> [Data processing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_processing) is, generally, "the collection and manipulation of
>   items of data to produce meaningful information." (...) it can
>   be considered a subset of information processing

According to these definitions,  data processing could be seen as a subset of computing.

However both terms were historically used interchangeably until a recent past. Because [the root of computing](https://www.google.be/amp/s/www.bbc.com/news/amp/blogs-magazine-monitor-35428300) is latin and means calculating, since early use of computers were mostly numeric calculation. So, in the early days making calculations or processing (mostly numeric) data was practically the same activity.